# Can someone explain the coincidence in probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The problem:
U choose 2 card from 52 normal card deck.(just normal card). What is the probability that first card is heart and the second is 10.

Answer: 1/52

Comment: note that 1/52 is the probability that choose a heart 10 card. The coincidence is cool. But I haven’t find a good way to explain it.

Comment: The punchline is that the suit of a particular card and the rank of another particular card are independent of one another.  Us being told that the first card was a heart does not bias our judgement in any way about what ranks are still available for the second card, they all remain equally likely in our eyes.

Comment: You can of course go through this calculation the tedious way, having looked at the $52\times 51$ different sequences of two cards being pulled... and having counted those where the first card was a heart and the second was a $10$, having correctly broken into cases based on if the first card was the $10\heartsuit$ or not, leading to a tedious calculation that ultimately results in what you found... $\frac{12\cdot 4 + 1\cdot 3}{52\cdot 51} = \frac{48+3}{52\cdot 51}=\frac{1}{52}$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following process of "constructing" a card:

- Draw one card, and record its suit.
- Draw a second card, and record its value.

Your constructed card is the combination of those two (the suit you recorded, and the value you recorded). It should be clear that each of the 52 cards are equally likely to be constructed in this process.

As @JMoravitz suggested in a comment, the essential fact here is that suits and values are independent variables. By recording the suit on the first card, but ignoring the value, we expect to see any possible value with equal likelihood when we pick up the second card.

Comment: But u should draw the card without replacement. So after we draw one card, the total number minus 1. The total number affect the probability of 10. How can heart and 10 be independent?

Comment: If you ignore the value of the first card, and don't record it, then what has *really* changed since the beginning of the problem?

To make it more obvious: suppose that I draw the cards, and only I look at them, and I decide what information to tell you. If all I tell you is the suit of the first card, why would your assessment of any card's value change?

Comment: You might find the answers linked under the duplicate tag to be helpful. (Apparently, I provided one of those answers too, and then I **completely** forgot all about it.)